# Resonance Frequency in a Tube

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics, resonance

I am trying to design a physical experiment to find the acoustic resonance frequencies of a plastic, cylinder pipe, to draw an analogy to the workings of musical instruments such as a flute. However, I am uncertain about whether the physics of a cylinder open at one, or both ends applies to my case. For example, if a person is playing the flute, they are closing one end of it with their mouth, while the opposite end remains open, will the length of the flute contain half the sound wave wavelength (cylinder open at both ends), or a quarter of the wavelength (open at one end). Furthermore, what is the case for an experiment I designed where a sound frequency generator is placed (not fully covering an end) at one end of the tube, sending a frequency through it, and a microphone (covering an end) is placed at the other? How should the setup be best manipulated to imitate a musical instrument given a plastic tube? Do the physics of a tube open at one end or both apply to an instrument such as a flute and hence the tube?

Feeling clueless. Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to clarify what instrument you are talking about, since you say "if a person is playing the flute, they are closing one end of it with their mouth", which is not how flutes are played. Instead a flute "[produces its sound from the flow of air across an opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flute)" , so they are modelled as a [tube open at both ends](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/flute.html). Many other wind instruments, e.g.[clarinets](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/flutes.v.clarinets.html), are tubes open at one end because the mouth does cover one end.

Comment: @David Bailey, what about a trumpet, would it also be modeled as a tube opened at both ends? And what about the fact that in the experiment a ball microphone is at inserted the end of the tube, does a sound recording device render the tube closed at one end, so should it be removed and put further from the tube, or a smaller microphone should be used to better model the workings of a trumpet?

Comment: If the mouth covers one end of an instrument,  as is the case for a trumpet, it is not a tube open at both ends. Trumpets are complicated because the tube is not a constant diameter (google "horn equation") and there are [mouthpiece](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/brassa.html#c3) and [bell](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/brassa.html#c2) effects. Inserting the microphone inside the instrument can affect the sound, so keep it outside. You can experiment with different positions.